# XMLHttpRequest "PUT"

Tags: javascript, http, browser, xmlhttprequest, put

I know how to `"GET"` data using `XMLHttpRequest()`, and would also like to use `XMLHttpRequest()` to `"PUT"` data to a file. The data I would like to `"PUT"` is just plain text. There is much on how to `"GET"` data, but I have done much research and have not found much on how to `"PUT"`data. There are a few questions online trying to do something similar but usually to `"POST"` instead, and none I found show a working model. Some say that for `"POST"`ing or `"PUT"`ing data, its `"Content-type"` must be `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and never `"text/plain"`. I would like to do my request synchronously and not use Node.js instead. To what I have found, this (below) seems to be the way to `"PUT"` data, but does not work.

How should data be `"PUT"` using `XMLHttpRequest()`?

```
var string = encodeURIComponent("Text String!");
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PUT", "example/data.txt", false);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", string.length);
req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
req.send(string);
```

I have tried `"text/plain"` as the `"Content-type"`, but the browser console gives me a "syntax error" in the resource I want to replace or tells me "no element found" if the resource is blank.

Comment: Have you tried putting using curl or fiddler?, is your endpoint configured for PUTs

Comment: Try an async request. Sync XHR is deprecated, and might throw exceptions on unconventional requests (CORS, PUT, etc). Also, you shouldn't need to set `Content-length`, the browser does that for you automatically.

Comment: @Bergi, I have tried an async request and commented out the `Content-length`, but that returns the same result in the console as the sync request and no change in the resource acted upon by `"PUT"`.

Comment: I'm stuck in this statement - `the browser console gives me a "syntax error" in the resource I want to replace` - can't for the life of me understand what you're trying to say here. Can you post the exact browser console message please

Comment: @JaromandaX, the browser (Firefox) said exactly `"syntax error data.txt:1:1"`, and `data.txt` is the file I am requesting to `"PUT"` to. Nothing gets put to `data.txt`. This is when `data.txt` contains text. If `data.txt` is empty, Firefox says exactly, `"no element found data.txt:1:1"`.

Comment: and that's in firefox console is it? - doesn't look like a browser side error, looks more like a server side error

Comment: @JaromandaX, It can read data from `"data.txt"` by requesting `"GET"`

Answer (score 0):

PUT creates or replaces a resource. As such, the Content-Type header field should contain the content type of the representation you are sending. For further details see [section 4.3.4 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4).

Comment: I know that "PUT" creates or replaces a resource and have tried "text/plain" as the "Content-type", but the browser console gives me a syntax error in the resource I want to replace or tells me no element found if the resource is blank.